# How to add a spreadsheet in Read the Docs?

Tags: python, markdown, spreadsheet, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

What's the best way to add a spreadsheet to my documentation using Read the Docs?

I'm working on an open-source project that produces open-source hardware and software. A ubiquitous section of open-source hardware projects' documentation is a [Bill of Materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_of_materials) section, which usually comes in the form of a spreadsheet listing what parts or raw materials need to be purchased to build the hardware product. Each row of the BOM spreadsheet contains at least the item's name/id, quantity, hyperlink to where it can be purchased, and the item's price.

At the end of the BOM is usually a total price, which is a sum of the (price*qty) of previous rows.

Read the Docs supports making tables. Is there any way to add a row at the end of the table such that one field in that row contains a formula that's used to derive the value of that cell's value when the documentation is compiled? Ideally in a way that doesn't require client-side javascript?

Or, more generally, does Read the Docs support adding spreadsheets to their documentation?

Comment: From this guide about using tables in sphinx/rtd: "the CSV can also be managed in an external file. This allows you to manage your complex tables in a third party tool, and have your documentation consume them from a CSV which is a much nicer workflow" https://www.ericholscher.com/blog/2016/jul/1/sphinx-and-rtd-for-writers/#tables Is there an example of this workflow anywhere?

Comment: Re html to pdf below, [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) can do that, with a pdf writer such as pdflatex. See [SO questions/tagged/pandoc+pdf+html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandoc+pdf+html)

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box Sphinx does not have any feature to do what you want. It can render static [tables](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#tables) from a CSV file via [`csv-table`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#csv-table) syntax.

However you could embed a spreadsheet hosted on a third party service via the [`raw`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through) directive.

```
.. raw:: html

    <iframe src="https://remote.sheet/filepath"></iframe>
```

Comment: what would be put in-place for the embed when the documentation is rendered to a pdf file?

Comment: raw:: html sections will be completel skipped for PDF. I personally include raw:: pdf with something like "Sorry, but this content can't be viewed in PDF. Please see HTML version instead".

Comment: oh wow! I thought maybe the iframe would fail to render to PDF, but *all* html?!? I'm surprised someone hasn't implemented a way to turn html into PDF; shouldn't be too hard to do..